# Shall I install update for my self installed emacs?

Tags: updates, software-installation, emacs

Yesterday, I installed the latest Emacs 24.4-1 from its official site by compiling its source code, because the one in repository is older.

But today the software update notifies me if I want to install software update including emacs:

```
Changes for emacs versions:
Installed version: 24.4-1
Available version: 45.0ubuntu1

Version 45.0ubuntu1: 

  * Default to emacs24.


Version 45.0: 

  * Provide the emacs metapackage (previously produced by emacs23,
    emacs24, etc.).

  * Set the initial dependencies to Emacs 23 (for the wheezy release).

  * Set the initial version higher than any existing emacs binary package.
```

I am not clear about what it says. Does it ask me to replace my self-installed newer version of emacs with the older version in ubuntu repository?
What shall I choose to do?

There are also other emacs-related packages. Shall I install them?

Can I ask the software update not to notify me to replace my newer version self-installed software with the old ones in repository?

My Ubuntu is 64-bit 14.04.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Some packages:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd skip the upgrade, since the actual emacs version in the repositories is still 24.3.

Comment: If you created a Debian package for emacs 24.4, I'd suggest doing that again, but editing `debian/control` to add `1:` before the version number (like `1:24.4-1`). The `1:`, an epoch number, should grant the custom package priority over anything `emacs` from the repository is likely to have.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of Ubuntu there is no longer any difficulty in updating the latest stable version of emacs. If you install the emacs snap package it will be updated automatically in the background. In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install emacs --classic
```

Snap packages have been installable in Ubuntu since Ubuntu 14.04 if snapd is installed using `sudo apt install snapd`. In Ubuntu 16.04 and later the snapd package is installed by default.

Similarly you can install the latest versions of many other common applications by searching for their snap packages in the Software app. An example is this question: [New to Linux, trying to install FFmpeg but missing dependencies from LibaV](https://superuser.com/q/1561355/) where installing the ffmpeg snap package which has no dependencies resolved a `The following packages have unmet dependencies:` error message that occurred when trying to install ffmpeg with `sudo apt install ffmpeg`.

Comment: Thanks. Is apt itself not able to do that?

Comment: Sometimes apt is able to keep of with snap packaging, but in general snap packages are able to keep up to date with the latest version better than apt packages. Snap packages are not limited by the stricter schedule of the Debian packaging scheme which allows snap packages to be automatically updated every few weeks if necessary, including major version upgrades. For example NetBeans 12.0 (snap) vs. NetBeans 10.0 (apt) in Ubuntu 18.04. The version of NetBeans usually refers to its target Java  version.