# install a package moved to /var/cache/apt/archives manually?

Tags: apt

I installed `wkhtmltopdf`, by `sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf`. Its version is 0.9.9.

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html says its latest stable version is 0.12.2.1. So I download its deb for Ubuntu 14.04.

I want to use `apt` to install the downloaded deb for reasons stated in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159114/674 and related replies, so I  move it to `/var/cache/apt/archives`, but still how can I install it using `apt`?

```
$ mv /tmp/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives

$ sudo apt-get install wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb'

$ sudo apt-get install wkhtmltox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wkhtmltox
```

`$ sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf` still installs the older version. Thanks.

Comment: Not without creating a repository: http://askubuntu.com/a/84323/158442. You can get dependencies installed by double-clicking on the package and thus using the Software Centre.

Comment: Thanks, @muru. Can you also take a look at my related question http://askubuntu.com/questions/595063/shall-i-install-update-for-my-self-installed-emacs? do you recommend me to create a repository to solve that problem too?

Comment: I don't think creating a repository would solve that problem.

Comment: Visit [offline repository](http://askubuntu.com/a/84323/256099) method of [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/974/256099) question. Or [APT offline repository method](https://sites.google.com/site/debianpackagemanagement/setting-local-repository) for installing package by **apt** may help you

Comment: @Tim And why `Unable to locate package`? : [This](http://askubuntu.com/q/481354/256099) can help you.

Answer (score 9):

#### Quick Summary

To install a manually downloaded .deb package and also automatically download and install the packages it depends on from your configured repositories:

- You can run `sudo apt-get -f install` after installing your .deb with `dpkg -i`.
- *Or* use `gdebi` to install a .deb package and automatically resolve its dependencies (`apt-get` will not do this, but `gdebi` and its graphical frontends will).

See below for details.

#### Why `apt-get` Won't Do This

`apt-get` checks your configured software sources (repositories) and automatically downloads and installs packages. Except in the case where a configured repository is inaccessible, this does not enable an `apt-get install` command to succeed that would not otherwise succeed. If the package isn't in one of your repositories, `apt-get` will not know to install it even if the .deb file happens to be in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Thus:

- If you have a package already downloaded, and it is the same package `apt-get` would automatically download and install, *then* you can put it `/var/cache/apt/archives` and `apt-get` will not have to download it.
- If you have a package already downloaded which is *not* the same package `apt-get` would automatically choose, but which *is nonetheless available* in a configured repository, then you can put it in `/var/cache/apt/archives` and force `apt-get` to attempt to install it instead of the package it prefers. For example:

  ```bash
  sudo apt-get install abiword=3.0.1-1
  ```
- Neither of those situations applies to your case. The *specific package version* is not provided by any of the configured repositories, because it is instead an alpha testing version from the upstream project's [download page](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html). Because you have no repository that provides *that version* of *that package*, you cannot install your manually downloaded .deb file with `apt-get`.

#### Way 1: Install with `dpkg` and Resolve Dependencies with `apt-get`

Fortunately, it doesn't look like you need to install this package with `apt-get`. It appears your actual goal is

1. to install the manually downloaded .deb package, which isn't provided by your repos (which `dpkg` can do, but `apt-get` cannot), and *also*
2. to install any its dependencies that *are* provided by its repos (which `dpkg` cannot do, but `apt-get` can).

You can do this in two separate steps:

1. Install the package with `dpkg`.

   ```bash
   sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
   ```
2. That created missing dependencies. `apt-get` can fix missing dependencies automatically.

   ```bash
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```

   That should also automatically finish configuring the original package. (So you will not likely need to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` yourself.)

#### Way 2: Use `gdebi` to Both Install and Resolve Dependencies

While `apt-get` won't attempt to automatically install an arbitrary .deb file and its dependencies, there is a tool made for this purpose: [gdebi](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gdebi) [image: Install gdebi]. From [`man gdebi`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gdebi.1.html):

> gdebi  lets you install local deb packages resolving and installing its dependencies. apt does the  same,  but  only  for  remote  (http,  ftp) located packages.

To use gdebi in a terminal, run `gdebi package.deb` as root, e.g.:

```
sudo gdebi wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

gdebi also has graphical frontends. You'll probably want to use [`gdebi-gtk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gdebi-gtk.1.html), the GTK+ frontend:

```
gksudo gdebi-gtk wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

But if you're running Kubuntu (or otherwise using KDE) you might prefer [`gdebi-kde`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gdebi-kde.1.html), the KDE frontend (provided by the [gdebi-kde](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gdebi-kde) [image: Install gdebi-kde] package):

```
kdesudo gdebi-kde wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

The graphical frontends may also be called without arguments (e.g., `gksudo gdebi-gtk`), in which case you may click File > Open to browse for and select the .deb file from within the GUI.

[image: Screenshot of the Open Software Package dialog in gdebi-gtk]

Comment: You don't need gdebi at all. The Software Centre can install dependencies. Just do `xdg-open foo.deb`

Comment: @muru Yes, you're right: one can even run `software-center package.deb` (or double-click the package to open it in USC, [as per your comment on the question](https://askubuntu.com/q/620056#comment876248_620056)). Btw the Software Center [warns users about "bad quality" .deb packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/111959/22949), which with alpha software--like in the OP's use case--might be considered either particularly useful or an unnecessary annoyance. ...Overall, the Software Center is a good solution, so I can expand this post--but it might be even better if you were to post a separate answer.

Comment: nah, one awesome answer >>  many fragmented answers.

Comment: using `dpkg --unpack` instead of `dpkg --install` will avoid the warning (and non-zero exit status) from unresolved dependencies. Especially useful when writing robust shell scripts that exit on errors.

Comment: @PhilFrost I fail to see the value of having a "robust script" that silently installs a package in a broken state. If you're fixing it right after, just `dpkg -i a.deb || true` and you can have your script "robust" (Hint: Robust means that the script does the right thing, not that it doesn't fail with expected errors: you handle those, because they're expected)

Comment: @sehe So what happens if `a.deb` doesn't exist, the user doesn't have permissions, or the filesystem is full? Running `apt-get install -f` after those errors is the *wrong thing*, but if you are ignoring *all* errors with `|| true`, you can't really do the Right Thing, can you? `dpkg -i` in this case accomplishes the same thing as `dpkg --unpack`, and then it proceeds to attempt to install the package, which you know will fail (that's why you are running `apt-get install -f`). With `--unpack` you avoid the error in the expected case, so you can do the Right Thing with the unexpected errors.

Comment: @PhilFrost Excellent points. Thanks for correcting my habits :)

Answer (score 7):

To install a locally stored `.deb` package use `dpkg`. Try:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/your/package.deb
```

`apt` takes care of the dependency problems which `dpkg` can not.

There is an interesting project [dpkg-offline](https://launchpad.net/dpkg-offline) which is currently under development. To quote from the `README` of the project,

```
This tool will download a set of .deb packages needed to install all of the given <packages-to-download>, with their dependencies satisfied, on an installation done from <base-iso>.
```

You can check out the development version of the tool [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~roadmr/dpkg-offline/trunk/files). I did not try it, so don't know how (un)stable it is.

[Here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~roadmr/dpkg-offline/trunk/view/head:/TUTORIAL.rst) is a tutorial from the dev branch in Launchpad on how to install and use `dpkg-offline`.

**Bonus** There is going to be a `show and tell` [event](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uos-1505/meeting/22464/a-tool-to-bundle-dependencies-for-a-package-for-offline-installation/) on this package in the Ubuntu Online Summit on 2015-05-06 at 15:00.

Comment: I was faster :)

Comment: ..and I'll give a +1 for that! :P

Comment: Here's yours :)

Answer (score 4):

`apt-get` can't install a `deb` package, use `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks. But why did the reply and other replies here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159114/674 recommend me to

Comment: `apt` takes care of the dependency problems which `dpkg` can not.

Comment: @Tim May I quote this sentence from the [answer on U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159114/674): _"(it will work if the .deb package is present in the apt package list)"_

Comment: @Byte: How can I make the .deb package  present in the apt package list?

Comment: @Tim I don't know, but you might want to look here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=45885 - otherwise: google is your friend! :D